# GeoServer 2.23 error when opening layer preview

Tags: geoserver, sql-server, rendering

I've made a fresh new installation of **GeoServer v2.23.2** on a Windows Server 2019 machine, running on **Java SE v11.0.20+9-LTS-256**.

Everything seems to work, except for the layer preview...
Whenever I try to preview a layer, this is the error I get:

```
26 053 09:53:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.demo.mappreviewpage, QueryString: 81&filter=false'; against '/web/**'
26 053 09:53:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.security] - Matched Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.demo.mappreviewpage, QueryString: 81&filter=false with /web/**
26 053 09:53:53 TRACE  [filter.GeoServerSecurityMetadataSource] - Did not match request to org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityMetadataSource$LoginPageRequestMatcher@77aa566a - [] (1/4)
26 053 09:53:53 TRACE  [filter.GeoServerSecurityMetadataSource] - Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/web/resources/**'] - [] (2/4)
26 053 09:53:53 TRACE  [filter.GeoServerSecurityMetadataSource] - Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/config/**'] - [ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR] (3/4)
26 053 09:53:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
26 053 09:53:53 DEBUG  [geoserver.filters] - Compressing output for mimetype: text/html;charset=utf-8
26 053 09:53:53 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of E:\Services\GeoServer\Data\gwc-layers
26 053 09:53:53 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 2ms for E:\Services\GeoServer\Data\gwc-layers
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'geoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'geoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'geoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'geoserver.xframe.shouldSetPolicy' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'geoserver.xframe.policy' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [filter.GeoServerSecurityMetadataSource] - Did not match request to org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityMetadataSource$LoginPageRequestMatcher@77aa566a - [] (1/4)
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [filter.GeoServerSecurityMetadataSource] - Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/web/resources/**'] - [] (2/4)
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [filter.GeoServerSecurityMetadataSource] - Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/config/**'] - [ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR] (3/4)
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher@53ca5ad5] and 1 interceptors
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [ows.Dispatcher] - Applying default cacheSeconds=-1
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[istat], available services were []
26 053 09:53:56 INFO   [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[istat], available services were []
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[istat], available services were []
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [sqlserver.jtds] - Failed to find JTDS jar
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [sqlserver.jtds] - Failed to find JTDS jar
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[istat], available services were []
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'org.geoserver.service.disabled' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - Getting layers and styles from LAYERS and STYLES
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - establishing polygon style for istat:TEST_V_Comuni
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[istat], available services were []
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[istat], available services were []
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[istat], available services were []
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [geoserver.wms] - setting up map
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[istat], available services were []
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[istat], available services were []
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'ENABLE_OL3' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'ENABLE_OL3' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'ENABLE_OL3' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'ENABLE_OL3' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[istat], available services were []
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[istat], available services were []
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Property override: 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Java environment variable : 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found Servlet context parameter : 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 TRACE  [geoserver.platform] - Found System environment variable : 'PROXY_BASE_URL' to be unset
26 053 09:53:56 INFO   [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
    Angle = 0.0
    BaseUrl = http://geoserver.mycompany.local:8080/geoserver/
    Bbox = SRSEnvelope[6.626621368537682 : 18.520381599098922, 35.493691935511414 : 47.09178374646218]
    BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
    Buffer = 0
    Clip = null
    CQLFilter = null
    Crs = GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
    SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
  PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
  UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
  AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
    Elevation = []
    Env = {}
    Exceptions = SE_XML
    FeatureId = null
    FeatureVersion = null
    Filter = null
    Format = application/openlayers
    FormatOptions = {}
    Get = true
    Height = 748
    Interpolations = []
    Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@f79b6e39]
    MaxFeatures = null
    Palette = null
    RawKvp = {REQUEST=GetMap, SRS=EPSG:4326, FORMAT=application/openlayers, BBOX=6.626621368537682,35.493691935511414,18.520381599098922,47.09178374646218, VERSION=1.1.0, STYLES=, SERVICE=WMS, WIDTH=768, HEIGHT=748, LAYERS=istat:TEST_V_Comuni}
    RemoteOwsType = null
    RemoteOwsURL = null
    Request = GetMap
    RequestCharset = UTF-8
    ScaleMethod = null
    Sld = null
    SldBody = null
    SldVersion = null
    SortBy = null
    SortByArrays = null
    SRS = EPSG:4326
    StartIndex = null
    StyleBody = null
    StyleFormat = sld
    Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=polygon]]
    StyleUrl = null
    StyleVersion = null
    Tiled = false
    TilesOrigin = null
    Time = []
    Transparent = false
    ValidateSchema = false
    Version = 1.1.0
    ViewParams = null
    Width = 768
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [geoserver.filters] - Compressing output for mimetype: text/html; subtype=openlayers3
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - Getting layers and styles from LAYERS and STYLES
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - establishing polygon style for istat:TEST_V_Comuni
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[istat], available services were []
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[istat], available services were []
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [config.impl] - Could not locate service of type interface org.geoserver.wms.WMSInfo in workspace WorkspaceInfoImpl[istat], available services were []
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [geoserver.wms] - setting up map
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [renderer.lite] - Computed scale denominator: 8735660.375448713
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [renderer.lite] - creating rules for scale denominator - 8,735,660.375
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
26 053 09:53:56 DEBUG  [data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
26 053 09:53:56 ERROR  [renderer.lite] - org/h2/jdbc/JdbcClob
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/h2/jdbc/JdbcClob
    at org.geotools.data.h2.H2ClobConverterFactory.createConverter(H2ClobConverterFactory.java:41)
    at org.geotools.util.Converters.convert(Converters.java:147)
    at org.geotools.util.Converters.convert(Converters.java:117)
    at org.geotools.filter.LiteralExpressionImpl.evaluate(LiteralExpressionImpl.java:136)
    at org.geotools.styling.visitor.Measure.processLiteralExpression(Measure.java:94)
    at org.geotools.styling.visitor.Measure.<init>(Measure.java:62)
    at org.geotools.styling.visitor.UomRescaleStyleVisitor.rescale(UomRescaleStyleVisitor.java:91)
    at org.geotools.styling.visitor.UomRescaleStyleVisitor.rescaleStroke(UomRescaleStyleVisitor.java:140)
    at org.geotools.styling.visitor.UomRescaleStyleVisitor.visit(UomRescaleStyleVisitor.java:198)
    at org.geotools.styling.PolygonSymbolizerImpl.accept(PolygonSymbolizerImpl.java:140)
    at org.geotools.styling.visitor.DuplicatingStyleVisitor.copy(DuplicatingStyleVisitor.java:511)
    at org.geotools.styling.visitor.DuplicatingStyleVisitor.lambda$visit$0(DuplicatingStyleVisitor.java:282)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.geotools.styling.visitor.DuplicatingStyleVisitor.visit(DuplicatingStyleVisitor.java:284)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.rescaleFeatureTypeStyle(StreamingRenderer.java:2628)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.applyUnitRescale(StreamingRenderer.java:2502)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.createLiteFeatureTypeStyles(StreamingRenderer.java:2069)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:2238)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:919)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:546)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:205)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:82)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:203)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:113)
    at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:250)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor405.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:38)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:57)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:32)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:64)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:43)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:51)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127.getMap(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor366.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:867)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1656)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.HTTPMethodFilter.doFilter(HTTPMethodFilter.java:36)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:194)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilterInternal(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    ... 142 more
```

All layers are configured from a `SQL Server` data source.

This is the list of installed modules on GeoServer:

[image: GeoServer modules list]

This installation should be a replacement for an older one (GeoServer v2.21) where all those layers are currently working. On that server all the layers work correctly and the layer preview is working too.

The GeoServer Data folder on the new installation is a copy of the previous machine's one. Anyway, I've also made some checks:

- Database connections works.
- Styles are valid (but I don't see the preview icon when I select one of my styles...)
- Existing layers seems to be correct (table, geometry type, bounds, ID field)
- I've created a brand new layer using a default style ("`polygon`") but I got the same error

This is the data table structure of one of the layers that gives the error:

[image: Table data structure]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does your layer contain `clob` objects as one of the row types?

Comment: I've added the data table structure of one of the layers that gives me the error. Other layers are more or less the same, so the only "uncommon" data type is `geometry`.

Comment: Possibly we're missing a jar in the packaging associated with the JTDS error, or need to switch to the `jre11` as well.

Comment: @BradHards Should the problem be solved using a previous version of GeoSever (which one?) or using a different JRE version (which one?)?

Comment: @BradHards Are you planning a new package release?

Comment: I'm not personally, but GeoServer releases are timed. See https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Release-Schedule . If the underlying question is whether the fix for your issue might be included - that depends on someone doing the work.

Comment: @BradHards Ok. Then, I need a fix or at least a workaround. I'm asking if there's any or if I can pick up a different (but recent) version of GeoServer that doesn't have the same issue.

Comment: @CheshireCat If I knew, or had time for a fix, there would be an answer (as opposed to a comment). You could try logging a JIRA ticket, but there are a lot of requests, and very few people doing the work. The geoserver web site has a list of commercial support organisations - I'm not associated with any.

Answer (score 1):

After opening a ticket on GeoServer Jira, it came out that it was a problem related to **H2 JDBC JAR package** that was added when installing Backup/Restore community plugin.

This is the link to the [Jira ticket - Backup-restore community module should not depend on H2](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/GEOS/issues/GEOS-11158).

Finally, the fix can be either removing the `gt-jdbc-h2` JAR from `webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib` folder or add the H2 extension module, that contains the JDBC driver.